# TypeError: fs.readdir is not a function in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a Blog posting project in React.js
But, I'm new to Js itself.

What I'm trying to do is, reading the list of files from the directory.

```
 const fs = require("fs");
 const path = require("path");
 const dirPath = path.join(__dirname,"../data/blogs/");
 const getBlog = async () => {
     await fs.readdir(dirPath,(err, files) => {
         if(err) {
             return console.log("Failed to list contents of directory: " + err)
         }
         console.log(files)
         files.forEach((file,i) => {
             fs.readFile(`${dirPath}/${file}` , "utf8" , (err,contents) => {
             })
         })
     })
 }
```

I tried to do it from a YouTube video. But I got an error something like this.

[image: TypeError]

Do I have to explicitly install **fs** into my project?

Then I saw some people doing

```
 const fs = require("fs").promises;
```

instead of

```
 const fs = require("fs");
```

I tried that too.

I also read some documentation from the node.js([Documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_options_callback))

```
import { readdir } from "fs/promises";
```

And tried to import that too. Didn't work saying that fs/promises not found.

Idk what exactly is the problem.

*Do I have to do something in package.json?*

*Do I have to install fs?If so how?*

I saw stackoverflow answers but none provided clarity. I'm using *React.js* with *Tailwindcss*.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to execute the code serverside or clientside?
I think fs can only be used on serverside, since it's part of nodeJS.

Comment: Thank you, but how exactly do I do that? 

Should I place it in the Public folder?